# How to extract child data with pugixml?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, pugixml

I am experimenting with pugixml to extract data from a large XML file. I only am interested in  the values of the values in the nodes BAR and Nm:

```
    <Document xmlns="xxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="vvvvvvv">
      <Outer>
        <HDR>
          <MsgId>FOOBAR222222</MsgId>
          <ID>
            <AAAAA>FOOBAR222222</AAAAA>
          </ID>
        </HDR>
        <ENTRY>
          <Status>existing</Status>
          <ELEM>
            <TM>2012-11-19T13:00:00</TM>
          </ELEM>
          <FOO>
            <BAR>xxxxx</BAR>
            <NM>
              <Nm>yyyyyyy</Nm>
            </NM>
          </FOO>
        </ENTRY>
```

From what I saw, it's possible to walk the root document, however, I am getting a bit lost on accessing parent and child nodes:

```
        void walk(xml_node parent)
        {
            for(xml_node child = parent.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling())
            {
              // ... Would like to output:  "FOO: xxxx  / NM:  yyyyyyyy"
            }
        }
```

Comment: another helpful link was: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/samples/traverse_iter.cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give parameters to the `first_child()` and other member functions:

```
auto Outer = document.first_child("OUTER");
auto Entry = Outer.first_child("ENTRY");
auto Foo = Entry.first_child("FOO");
```

etc.

When you finally get to the destination, use `.value()` to get to the node value.

PugiXML also features XPath support, but that would probably be overkill in that case.

Comment: thanks! what about if ENTRY is repeated several times, does the first_child selection work then? I would need to loop over all ENTRYs... that was not clear in my question, sorry!

Comment: Then use `Foo = Foo.next_sibling("FOO")`, to get to the next Foo node :)

Comment: great! now, I get the idea... just small additional question, trying to ouse a parameter for first_child gives:  no matching function for call to ‘pugi::xml_node::first_child(const char [9])’

Answer (score 0):

Pugi has also a simple path facility [5.10. Miscellaneous functions](http://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#access.misc)

You could do the above with just one line:

```
document.first_element_by_path("/Document/Outer/ENTRY/FOO/BAR").first_child().value();
```